# Localize g++ compile options within code

Tags: c++11, compiler-optimization, pragma, compiler-directives, g++4.9

I'm looking for a simple way to localize certain g++ (g++-4.9 to be specific) compile options to certain lines of code or at least targeted functions.  I'm interested generally speaking, but also specifically to the `-fast-math`, `-ffinite-math-only` and `-fno-signed-zeros` options.

I  presume that localization at the *.cpp file level is possible with `make` utility, but I'm hoping there is a way to enable it in the code itself, through #pragma or __attribute__ or something.  I want to do this not only to minimize dependencies to external files (i.e. risk of incorrect `makefile`) but also to hopefully hyperlocalize certain FP behavior to specific equations within a function.

Alternatively, if localization of FP behavior by inline directives is NOT possible, what can I do to at least trigger a compile time error if desired compiler directive is NOT enabled in project build (e.g. `makefile` is lost or inappropriately modified).

I would presume that such inline optimization might be compiler specific, g++ in this case, but that is a compromise I'm willing to take.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `gcc` you can use [function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) `optimize`:

```
void f () __attribute__ ((optimize("fast-math"), optimize("finite-math-only"), optimize("no-signed-zeros")));
```

Comment: Thanks. I had found some tutorials/help discussing \__attribute__ used with optimization levels (e.g. O0,O1,O2) but it was not obviously to me, from the description, that it also applied to other options like fast-math, etc.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>I'm not sure that you are using the "localize" word correctly. [Localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) is related to adapting software to users of different human languages (French, Russian, Chinese...)</sup>

Perhaps you want to ask the compiler to optimize *some* functions with other optimization flags.

This is possible using [`#pragma GCC optimize`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html) etc... or using some [function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html)

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to turn on some bits of this with the `fpmath` option in a function attribute, but this was not clear to me from the docs. In light of that, I will focus on detection instead:

`-fast-math` already turns on `-ffinite-math-only`, so you don't need to worry about that. The docs for `-fast-math` say:

> This option causes the preprocessor macro **FAST_MATH** to be
>   defined.

Which means it can be detected via

```
#ifndef __FAST_MATH__
#error "The -fast-math compiler option is required"
#endif
```

I have not yet found a compile-time way to detect the presence of `-fno-signed-zeros`